# How to detect some Activex in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an activex plugin here:
http://reboltutorial.com/plugins/logo-badge/

I tried by adapting the script http://forums.devarticles.com/javascript-development-22/detecting-activex-objects-installed-in-ie-11041.html to

```
<script>
//if RPluginIE is not installed
if( !document.RPluginIE){
document.location.href = "Notfound.html"
}
</script>
```

but it doesn't work.

How to detect for any activex ?

Comment: There are some syntax errors in your code, like `document.loction.href`

Comment: thanks It was a copy and paste from the other site. I corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use a proper method for testing

```
// read more on http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/feature-detection-state-of-the-art-browser-scripting
function isHostMethod(object, property){
    var t = typeof object[property];
    return t == 'function' ||
        (!!(t == 'object' && object[property])) ||
        t == 'unknown';
}
```

Then your code would look like

```
if(!isHostMethod(window", "RPluginIE"){
     document.location.href = "Notfound.html";
}
```

Note that its the **window** we check, not the document.

Comment: Really great article, I couldn't find it while searching google, thanks.